# How is Simulated Annealing an "Adaptation of The Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm"?

Tags: optimization, markov-chains, monte-carlo

I'm trying to understand how simulated annealing is related to the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, that is, if they are at all. The Wikipedia page states that simulated annealing *"is an adaptation of the Metropolis–Hastings algorithm"*, and so far what I've come to think of it as is that simulated annealing basically uses the metropolis algorithm so the system relaxes into its ”ground state” to make the distribution easier to evaluate, and then slowly decreases the temperature to end up only accepting better points, so it eventually finds the global optimum.

I understand the Monte-Carlo Markov Chain aspect of their technical similarity; my main difficulty in seeing the connection is in the difference in the *acceptance criterion* (transition kernel) of both methods, between which I can't see any connection - one is a "simple" ratio between the current and the candidate, and the other is derived from the Boltzmann statistical distribution.

Is there an actual mathematical relationship between the two methods on the basis of their acceptance criterion, and is simulated annealing really a direct adaptation of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm?

Comment: This https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/453309/what-is-the-relationship-between-metropolis-hastings-and-simulated-annealing 
Might be helpful. Loosely speaking, the structure of the acceptance ratios is very similar except in simulated annealing, the you have the temperature that you change in each iteration

Comment: @Snildt Thanks for the reference, I had indeed gone through that answer before posting my own, and while it did confirm that the two were similar and differed "only" on the basis of the acceptance criterion, I wasn't really able to understand the mathematical similarity between the two and how they relate the two methods to each other - to my eyes, they're rather different, for example, why does the acceptance criterion for simulated annealing involve *e*?

Comment: In general, the Metropolis Hasting ratio is of the form 
$$\frac{q(y,x) \pi(y)}{q(x,y) \pi(x)}$$
Where $\pi$ is the distribution we want to sample from. There is no reason $\pi$ can't contain an $e$ as well. For example if we wanted to use MH to sample from the exponential distribution, the ratio would include $e$ as well. 
The $e$ when using simulated annealing comes from the density of Boltzmann distribution, since this is the distribution we want to sample from, only we vary the temperature parameter $T$

Comment: @Snildt I think I see what you mean, I can see the Metropolis ratio resolving into the criterion used for simulated annealing when applied to the Boltzmann distribution. Emphasis on only *Metropolis* though, I don't see Hastings' ratio (the proposal distribution conditional probability part - $\frac{q(y, x)}{q(x, y)}$ ) in the S.A. criterion - am I missing something here, and would this not imply that simulated annealing is only applicable to symmetric distributions?